# More efficient way to make images responsive without a bunch of different image sizes and media queries?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am working on a responsive website, so far everything is responsive except the logo (the logo is a PNG image). I understand I am able to use media queries but I have realized with this method I would need many versions of the same image with different sizes. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this? Also if media queries are the only option what dimensions should I make them so my website can look good on all devices. Thanks for all the help!

The only other thing I have tried/can think of is to use a % for the background but that still appears a it vertically stretched on mobile devices.

```html
  <div id="imgLogoDiv">
    <img id="imgLogo" src="/img/giphylogo_V1.png" alt="unable to load image">
  </div>
```

```css
#imgLogoDiv {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: auto;
}

#imgLogoDiv #imgLogo {
    width: 45%;
    height: auto;
    /*to make responsive use a % for width not px*/
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

    body {
        background-image: url(img/mobileBackground.jpg);
        background-position: top center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    /*This looks a bit better but there might be a better method.*/
    #imgLogoDiv #imgLogo {
        content: url("img/mobileLogo.png");
    }
}
```

[image: How website and logo looks on mobile]

Comment: Can you put the code in JSfiddle or pass a URL?

Comment: If you think the image is not currently responsive, or that you "would need many versions of the same image with different sizes", then you need to do some more research on what "responsive" means. You have a percentage-based width for you logo image, what more do you want?

Comment: @VitorAvanço here is the url: https://rocky-escarpment-83509.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand I am able to use media queries but I have realized with
>   this method I would need many versions of the same image with
>   different sizes.

There are few other options here.

Option 1 : Use a generic style. Bootstrap uses the class `img-fulid` to make the image fit in any viewport

```
.img-fluid {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

eg : `<img src='gify.gif' class='img-fluid' />`

Option 2: Leverage `sizes` and `srcset` attributes of image. So you can avoid using lot of media queries

```
<img srcset="elva-fairy-320w.jpg 320w,
             elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
             elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 320px) 280px,
            (max-width: 480px) 440px,
            800px"
     src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg" alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

More read on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works in many browsers, but has problem with Safari (iPhone). You need to change strategy and apply a fixed height to logo size when mobile:

```
<style>
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-image: url(img/mobileBackground.jpg);
        background-position: top center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    #imgLogoDiv #imgLogo {
       width: auto;
       height: 70px;
    }
}
</style>
```

**Removing content property**